# How to detect if a monitor is in standby mode?

Tags: windows

Under Windows, is there a way to determine programmatically if the primary monitor is in standby mode or not?

Answer (score 1):

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/441918-monitor-status

It is possible ...

Willy Denoyette's post halfway down the page has an example script.

Answer (score 0):

i dont exactly how to do it , but i remember there is a windows message for when the power management has changed..

here is an article on how to manipulate the monitor.

[Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Monitor_management_guide.aspx)

There might be a way to send a message and get a reply on the state of the monitor.